# Gulp - copy a file in all subdirectories

Tags: gulp

I want to copy a file `/stubs/foo.txt` in all the subdirectories of `/something/`, for example

```
/something/foo.txt
/something/else/foo.txt
```

I tried:

```
gulp.task('copy', function () {
    return gulp.src('/stubs/foo.txt')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/something/**/*'));
});
```

But it seems Gulp does not support variable in the destination folder.

Comment: gulp.dest() doesn't support Globs.
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, but you could use multiple destination pipes.